# Why isn't FeatureManagement working properly in Azure Function?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to fix feature management by using below NuGet package in the azure function. The last implementation I saw was always false When I change names like xxxxxxxEnabled or yyyyEnabled result is the same.

```
dotnet add package `Microsoft.FeatureManagement.AspNetCore`
```

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
.
.
.
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {},
  "FeatureFlags": {
    "xxxEnabled": true
  }
}
```

In Startup.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddFeatureManagement(_configuration.GetSection("FeatureFlags"));
```

And the last step is checking **true/false** But it always returns to me a false value. What is wrong here?

Calling method:

```
var r = _manager.IsEnabledAsync("xxxEnabled").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
if (await _manager.IsEnabledAsync("xxxEnabled"))
{
   await mymethod(order).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
else
{
  await mymethod2(order).ConfigureAwait(false);
}                            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the config file. Edit it to look like this:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "FeatureFlags__xxxEnabled": true
    },
    "ConnectionStrings": {}
}
```

Reason for this seems to be that Azure Functions do not like nested json in their config.